# How do I stop a Wordpress page from jumping/scrolling to an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, iframe

I have a Wordpress site, and a small iframe towards the bottom of the page. Whenever the page loads it jumps to where the iframe is.

I've tried hiding the element and adding a javascript function

HTML

```
<iframe id="iframe_wrapper" src="link-here" frameborder="0"
scroll="no" onload="showOnLoad();"></iframe>
```

CSS

```
#iframe_wrapper {display:none;}
```

JS

```
function showOnLoad() {
document.getElementById("iframe_wrapper").style.display = 'block';
}
```

The iframe appears, but it dind't fix the jumping issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the height to 1px

```
#iframe_wrapper {
  height:1px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

plz add "opacity:0" instead of "display:none".. check the below code..

**css**

```
#iframe_wrapper {
  opacity:0;
}
```

**js**

```
function showOnLoad() {
  document.getElementById("iframe_wrapper").style.opacity= '1';
}
```